# ruby on Rails: Merge 2 activerecord arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, merge

I Have 2 arrays such as:

```
arr1 : {[:day => 12, :sum_src => 1234], [:day => 14, :sum_src => 24543]}
arr2 : {[:day => 12, :sum_dst => 4234], [:day => 14, :sum_dst => 342334]}
```

I want to merge this two arrays into one, so that it looks like:

```
arr3 : {[:day => 12, :sum_src => 1234, :sum_dst => 4234],[:day => 14, :sum_src => 24543, :sum_dst => 342334]}
```

Is it possible? And how to do this ?

Comment: that doesnt look like an array to me, hashes?

Comment: I have fixed my first message

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off Qerub's answer - if the arrays are sorted as in the example zip can be a great tool for this:

```
arr1 = [{:day => 12, :sum_src => 1234}, {:day => 14, :sum_src => 24543}]
arr2 = [{:day => 12, :sum_dst => 4234}, {:day => 14, :sum_dst => 342334}]
arr1.zip(arr2).map {|a,b| a.merge!(b)}
```

Result

```
[{:day=>12, :sum_dst=>4234, :sum_src=>1234}, {:day=>14, :sum_dst=>342334, :sum_src=>24543}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Omar pointed out, those are hashes. If you have two hashes:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge(h2)   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
```

In your case, if you want to merge to arrays and remove repetitions, I would use Union operator:

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ] | [ "c", "d", "a" ] #=> [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
```

Taken from Rails API.
Good luck!

Comment: <%@sum_all = @sum_dst.merge(@sum_src)%>
undefined method `merge' for [#<Dst >, #<Dst >]:Array

Answer (score 0):

(You have mixed up the syntaxes for literal hashes and arrays, but anyway…)

Here's a short but slightly cryptic solution:

```
arr1 = [{:day => 12, :sum_src => 1234}, {:day => 14, :sum_src => 24543}]
arr2 = [{:day => 12, :sum_dst => 4234}, {:day => 14, :sum_dst => 342334}]

result = (arr1 + arr2).inject({}) { |mem, x|
  (mem[x[:day]] ||= {}).merge!(x); mem
}.values
```

Result:

```
[{:sum_dst=>4234, :day=>12, :sum_src=>1234}, {:sum_dst=>342334, :day=>14, :sum_src=>24543}]
```

A more readable version would probably have more explicit looping. (Left for the reader as an exercise.)